# Hinttext in the TextFormField is not aligned with the prefix and suffix Icon

Tags: flutter, android-edittext, flutter-layout, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

Some how the Hint text in the textformfield is a little bit elevated(feels as if it is upward incomparison to the two icons) in comparison to the prefix and suffix Icon.

[image]

I am also attaching the code that I am using for this TextFormfield:

```
TextFormField(
            style:
                w400.size12.copyWith(color: BrandColor.foodsearchViewTextColor),
            cursorColor: BrandColor.foodsearchViewTextColor,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      SvgAssets.food_search_icon,
                      color: BrandColor.foodsearchViewTextColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                ),
                suffixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 14.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      SvgAssets.food_searchview_suffix,
                      color: BrandColor.foodsearchViewTextColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: foodSearchText,
                hintStyle: w400.size12.copyWith(
                    color: BrandColor.foodsearchViewTextColor, fontSize: 13)),
          ),
```

I have also tried wrapping the textformfield with the center widget but it did not solve the problem.
I would really appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `contentPadding` parameter in `InputDecoration` like this

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15)
```

or

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)
```

You can set contentPadding globally with the help of `theme` in `MaterialApp`

```
theme: ThemeData(
            inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: But, this solution would just be for this screen, right? I am looking for a solution that is adaptive across various screen sizes.

Comment: You have defined the padding as a theme for the whole Project but my question remains the same. In some large screen mobiles this padding would work but in older and smaller screens, this might not be the right fix. I want a solution that can be adopted dynamically. Anyways, Thanks for this :)

Comment: Please check in all device. It's gonna be same.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Finally, I found a proper way to handle it.**

We can use **`TextButton`** as SuffixIcon. Most of the time we are required to apply text/loading to suffixes. We can provide any kind of widget to it.

Here is code sample,

```
                    TextFormField(
                        onSaved: (code) {
                          log(code!);
                        },

                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Enter your coupon code here",
                          suffixIcon: TextButton(
                            child: const Text(
                              "Apply",
                              style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the content padding and textAlign properties were not a solution cause i was also using a custom font.

My solution was to introduce padding around the prefix icon widget and make an adjustments on the offset values from left, right, top and bottom to find the perfect alignment between my TextFormField text and prefix icon.

**Example :**

```
TextFormField(
    style: TextStyle(
        color: darkBlueColor,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        fontFamily: 'Neue'),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: const Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0, top: 2.0, bottom: 8.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.email,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 28.0,
        ),
      ),
      hintText: hintText,
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          fontSize: 14.0,
          fontFamily: 'Neue'),
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
    ))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add the following properties to your text field:

1- `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center`

2- In InputDecoration add `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0)`

3- In IconButton add `padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0)`

[image]

```
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
    prefixIcon: Icon(
      Icons.search,
    ),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
      onPressed: null,
    ),
    hintText: "Search"
  )
)
```